# Adding a column to a queried table in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my Excel spreadsheet, I have a table with data queried from another workbook. I am interested in adding a "Notes" column to the end of the table to be able to add information to each row. I am also interesting in being able to sort the table and the "Notes" column together - i.e., maintaining the match between each cell in the "Notes" column and its matching row - and in maintaining this match when refreshing the query.

However, I run into problems both when I [keep the "Notes" column separate from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTf5T.png) and when I [make it part of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY8VQ.png). When I keep the "Notes" column separate, I am unable to sort the table and the column together (or at least I haven't found a way to be able to do this). When I add the "Notes" column to the table, although this solves the sorting problem, another problem arises, namely, that when I refresh the query, the cells in the "Notes" column get reordered and no longer match up with their original rows.

Is there a way for me to set up this "Notes" column such that I can achieve all my goals described above?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a unique column like an ID in the queried data?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, we can't add custom columns into a queried table because the queried table will be changed if we refresh the query. All range in the queried table will be overwritten after each refreshing.

Comment: Further to my question about the ID column, could you please edit your post and include paste a screenshot in there that shows some example rows and the kind of comment you would make? When you paste, it should create a link to an uploaded version of your image on imgur. That's fine, just leave it like that and save the edit.

Comment: @Owen Yes, there is an ID column, as you can see in the screenshots I have added to the question, as per your request. However, I was considering hiding this column, since I don't have much use for it (it was created automatically by Microsoft Forms). I don't know what solution you will suggest, but if it works even if I hide the ID column, that would be ideal.

Comment: The approach I've outlined below will work even if you hide the column in the Merged query, but the ID column must be available for the merge, otherwise there's no way of reliably linking a note with a unique row from the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your query, which is currently loading onto a in your workbook:

[image]

The issue here is that the results of this query might change - more rows might be added, rows might be removed, that kind of thing.

You want to retain permanent notes against some rows, but you have no way of knowing if they're going to be there next time you refresh the query (presumably).

So, it's best to maintain a list of notes in another sheet, in a structured table (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert the range to a structured table), something like this:

[image]

This on its own is not that useful, but it's your own reference data that enriches the query you are getting from elsewhere.

To ensure that the right note goes against the right person, you need to:

1. Create a query against your notes table (use Data>Get & Transform
   Data>From Table/Range to do this)
2. Close & Load this new query. You can then delete the tab that the query is loaded to, so you just have the connection to your notes table.

At this point, you have your query results from the other file, a table of your notes, and a connection to that table.

[image]

The reason you need to have a connection to the notes table, is so you can merge the two tables in the image above.

Use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Merge, and configure it like this:

[image]

This is the reason you needed the unique ID. It's important you use a LEFT JOIN in the above dialog.

In the query editor, click the double-arrow at the top of the column that has the word Table in every row. Deselect the ID field (leaving the note field selected), then click OK.

Now click Close & Load. This should load the merged query to a new sheet.

[image]

Now, you can refresh this query each time you refresh the original query and re-attach your notes that you may have created previously.

This may not seem ideal, but since the original query is subject to change, and you want to add some permanent data, this is a useful technique. You could then add rows to your notes table as they occur to you, perhaps with 2 windows of the same workbook, positioned like this:

[image]